# Replace in ColdFusion spoiling SQL query

Tags: coldfusion

I've got the below MySQL query, it's causing an error, the error is below too.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s.id as id, s.auctioneer as auctioneer, s.advertType as advertType, s.saleType as saleType, an.name as auctioneerName, st.entryCopy as saleTypeName, at.entryCopy as advertTypeName, s.heading AS heading, sl.city AS city, sd.id AS sdId, sd.startDate AS startDate
    FROM    sales s LEFT JOIN saleloc sl ON sl.saleId = s.id LEFT JOIN saledates sd ON sd.saleLoc = sl.id,
            auctioneers an,
            lookupcopy st,
            lookupcopy at
    #replace(findWhere,"''","'","all")# AND
    s.id = sd.saleId AND sl.saleId = s.id
    AND an.id = s.auctioneer
    AND st.id = s.saleType
    AND at.id = s.advertType
    GROUP BY id     
    ORDER BY startDate, auctioneerName, city
```

Error from database

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id as id, s.auctioneer as auctioneer, s.advertType as advertType, s.saleType as saleType, an.name as auctioneerName, st.entryCopy as saleTypeName, at.entryCopy as advertTypeName, s.heading AS heading, sl.city AS city, sd.id AS sdId, sd.startDate AS startDate
FROM sales s 
LEFT JOIN saleloc sl ON sl.saleId = s.id 
LEFT JOIN saledates sd ON sd.saleLoc = sl.id, auctioneers an, lookupcopy st, lookupcopy at 
'WHERE s.advertType > 0 
AND s.saleType > 0 
AND sl.region = "2" ' 
AND s.id = sd.saleId 
AND sl.saleId = s.id 
AND an.id = s.auctioneer 
AND st.id = s.saleType 
AND at.id = s.advertType 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY startDate, auctioneerName, city
```

I didn't write this code and I'm not sure why the #Replace()# is being used, can anyone see how to fix the syntax error it's causing?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for those with the same question, the replace is simply escaping any single quotes with two single quotes that would kill a query such as "teachers's pet".   The issue with the error query is additionally the where clause had single quotes at the beginning and end so those need to be stripped as well, as per the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Before the query code, do a replace as follows:

<cfset findWhere = Replace(findWhere, "''", "'", "ALL")#
<cfif Left(findWhere, 1) EQ "'">
    <cfset findWhere = Right(findWhere, Len(findWhere) - 1)>
</cfif>
<cfif Right(findWhere, 1) EQ "'">
    <cfset findWhere = Left(findWhere, Len(findWhere) - 1)>
</cfif>

<cfquery name="qry" datasource="mysql">
SELECT DISTINCT s.id as id, s.auctioneer as auctioneer, s.advertType as advertType, s.saleType as saleType, an.name as auctioneerName, st.entryCopy as saleTypeName, at.entryCopy as advertTypeName, s.heading AS heading, sl.city AS city, sd.id AS sdId, sd.startDate AS startDate
FROM    sales s 
LEFT JOIN saleloc sl ON sl.saleId = s.id 
LEFT JOIN saledates sd ON sd.saleLoc = sl.id,
        auctioneers an,
        lookupcopy st,
        lookupcopy at
#findWhere# AND
s.id = sd.saleId AND sl.saleId = s.id
AND an.id = s.auctioneer
AND st.id = s.saleType
AND at.id = s.advertType
GROUP BY id     
ORDER BY startDate, auctioneerName, city
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Also, I am not sure if MySQL is alright with the double quotes and you may need to replace the double quotes with single quotes around the region variable.

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in `findWhere` includes single-quotes at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Any idea for a remedy? How I can fix this?

Comment: Figure out why the data is coming to you that way, and correct that problem in the appropriate place (whatever sets `findWhere`, or potentially further upstream).

Answer (score 0):

On another note: Unless you created findWhere without any direct user input value, then you need to secure it.

Better to do:

```
...
WHERE 1= 1
<cfif listFind( 'foo' , findWhere )>
foo= 2

<cfelseif listFind( 'bar' , findWhere )>
bar= 209

</cfif>
...
```

Comment: Hi. Your answer has completely confused me, I'm not a CF developer, I'm having to try to fix this while ours is away. My skills are elsewhere. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: In CF use <cfqueryparam .. /> to secure your queries.

WHERE s.id= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype= "cf_sql_integer" value= "#id#" />

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I don't believe you can do a distinct and a group by statement in the same query.

They both do the same kind of thing, but for different reasons.